# How to dynamically set a button in an other class method without XML

Tags: java, android

This is my first time making an android application and I want it to be reusable for any other applications that I may make later on. Thats why I want to make a button class that dynamically makes a button without the use of XML. But when I want to do this the program crashes when I use the "setContentView" method in my makeButton method.

Also when I copy paste the contents of "makeButton" into the onCreate method it somehow works. Why does it work in the onCreate method and not in the "makeButton" method?

MainActivity.java

```java
package mw.mobilepccommunication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ButtonService button = new ButtonService("test", 100, 100, 100, 100, this);
        button.makeButton();

        //Contents of makeButton.
        Button mButton = new Button(this);
        mButton.setText("test");
        setContentView(mButton);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ButtonSerivce.java

```java
package mw.mobilepccommunication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ButtonService extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mNameButton;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mXBeginPoint;
    private int mYBeginPoint;

    private Button mButton;
    private Context mContext;


 public ButtonService(String aNameButton, int aHeight, int aWdith, int aXBeginPoint, int aYBeginPoint, Context aContext)
    {
        mNameButton = aNameButton;
        mHeight = aHeight;
        mWidth = aWdith;
        mXBeginPoint = aXBeginPoint;
        mYBeginPoint = aYBeginPoint;
        mContext = aContext;
    }

public void makeButton()
    {
        mButton = new Button(mContext);
        mButton.setText(mNameButton);
        setContentView(mButton); // <-- It fails here.
    }
}
```

Comment: ButtonService class this class you want to use only for add button or you trying to use it as second activity

Comment: I want to add the button to the first activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong in your understanding of process and Activity life cycle.

When you activity has been created by android system it going across several required [steps](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

The first time in activity life cycle it is attached to `Window`.
Consider the source code of `setContentView` method

```
public void More ...setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
       getWindow().setContentView(view, params); // retrieve attached window 
       initWindowDecorActionBar();
}
```

Since you Acrivity has not attached to window before, the `getWindow` method return null.

And that is why you application get crashed

### Update

If you like to add button to `MainActivity` try to do something like

```
public class ButtonService{

    private String mNameButton;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mXBeginPoint;
    private int mYBeginPoint;

    private Button mButton;
    private Activity mContext;


 public ButtonService(String aNameButton, int aHeight, int aWdith, int aXBeginPoint, int aYBeginPoint, Activity aContext)
    {
        mNameButton = aNameButton;
        mHeight = aHeight;
        mWidth = aWdith;
        mXBeginPoint = aXBeginPoint;
        mYBeginPoint = aYBeginPoint;
        mContext = aContext;
    }

public void makeButton()
    {
        mButton = new Button(mContext);
        mButton.setText(mNameButton);
        mContext.setContentView(mButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: But why doesn't the same happen in the onCreate method? I didn't assign a window to it there either.

Comment: Can you tell me the line where it work normally? Because I have not seen any other place, where you have used this class